# modify results of cusor from oracle based on results

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns a ref cursor. What I need to do is filter the results even further. Due to things being protected I'm not sure how much information I can give out. In the results there is an 'Editedflag' column. If that column value is 'Y' I need to get the 'PassID' column value and find the other result that has the same 'PassID' and remove it from the results. I am at a loss of what to even google for this type of question. Thanks.

```
SELECT  a.log_curv_id LogCurveId
        ,a.log_curv_type_id LogCurveTypeId
        ,c.log_curv_type_desc LogCurveTypeDesc
        ,a.cmpl_fac_id CompletionId
        ,d.fac_nme CompletionName
        ,b.edtd_curv_indc EditedIndicator
        ,b.stsfr_qlty_indc SatisfactoryIndicator
        ,a.top_md_qty TopMeasuredDepth
        ,a.base_md_qty BaseMeasuredDepth
        ,NVL(TO_NUMBER(eds.p_surv_load.fget_log_curv_spec(a.log_curv_id,2248)),NULL) FlowRate
        ,NVL(TO_NUMBER(eds.p_surv_load.fget_log_curv_spec(a.log_curv_id,800)),NULL) TubingPressure
        ,NVL(TO_NUMBER(eds.p_surv_load.fget_log_curv_spec(a.log_curv_id,2249)),NULL) LossAbove
        ,NVL(TO_NUMBER(eds.p_surv_load.fget_log_curv_spec(a.log_curv_id,2250)),NULL)LossBelow
        ,b.lggg_tlstr_pass_id PassId
        FROM eds.log_curv a,
        eds.acqn_curv b,
        eds.log_curv_type c,
        eds.fac_nme d
        WHERE a.log_curv_id = b.log_curv_id
        AND b.lggg_tlstr_pass_id = 188481
        AND a.log_curv_type_id = c.log_curv_type_id
        AND NVL(a.cmpl_fac_id,0) = d.fac_id(+)
        AND d.term_dttm IS NULL
        AND a.del_indc = 'N'
        AND b.del_indc = 'N'
        AND c.del_indc = 'N'
        AND d.fac_nme_type_cde = 'NME'  /*12/09/2013 ksk NEW*/
        AND d.del_indc = 'N';           /*12/09/2013 ksk NEW*/
```

Results

[image]

You will notice that the completion id is the same on the results. I need to check for the Y flag in the Editedindicator column and if present find the results that has the matching completionid and remove it.

Comment: A cursor is a read-only structure so you can't modify it.  You could fetch all the data from the cursor into a local collection or a global temporary table, write a query that modifies the data however you would like, and then return that to a caller as a separate cursor.  But that is far from an elegant approach.  I would generally prefer to modify the original procedure to handle the new requirement or to write a separate procedure that queries the same tables (possibly factoring some logic into a view) or to turn the first procedure into a pipelined table function.

Comment: This is something that I am able to do but I dont know oracle well enough to know where to begin.

Comment: Can you narrow the question down?  Are you asking how to fetch from a cursor?  How to write to a global temporary table?  How to create a global temporary table?  How to write the query that transforms the data from what the procedure returns to what you want?  How to refactor the original procedure in one of the ways I suggested to avoid the cursor to local storage to cursor hack?  Something else?

Comment: I am allowed to rewrite entire stored procedure if needed I have just never done something this complicated so I am not sure of the terms I need to google. From your suggestion I best case would be to rewrite my current stored procedure. I am more than willing to learn something new/hard and take this route.

Comment: Then it sounds like you want to post a test case showing the data you have and the results you want and we can help you figure out the SQL statement you'd want your rewritten stored procedure to run.

Comment: updated to show requested information

Comment: if more than one PassID was found, are you going to remove all of those  records or just one of them; if its the latter, which one of them or how do you determine which one is going to be removed, assuming that those records with the same PassID have different set of records under them?

Comment: To clarify, you can have multiple records with the same ID. Are you always going to be looking for the most recent record? If so, is there a column that you can use to identify what the most recent record is, such as a date field or incremental sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with yq as (
select  a.log_curv_id, a.log_curv_type_id, c.log_curv_type_desc, a.cmpl_fac_id, 
        d.fac_nme, b.edtd_curv_indc, b.stsfr_qlty_indc, a.top_md_qty, a.base_md_qty, 
        b.lggg_tlstr_pass_id PassId,
        count (case when edtd_curv_indc = 'Y' then 1 end) 
         over (partition by b.lggg_tlstr_pass_id) cnt
  from log_curv a
  join acqn_curv b     on b.del_indc = 'N' and a.log_curv_id = b.log_curv_id
  join log_curv_type c on c.del_indc = 'N' and a.log_curv_type_id = c.log_curv_type_id
  left join fac_nme d  on nvl(a.cmpl_fac_id,0) = d.fac_id and d.del_indc = 'N' 
                          and d.term_dttm is null and d.fac_nme_type_cde = 'NME'
  where b.lggg_tlstr_pass_id = 188481 and a.del_indc = 'N')
select yq.* from yq where (cnt>0 and edtd_curv_indc='Y') or cnt = 0
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db0fa/1)</sup>

In the query above I used analytic `count()` function to check if exists rows with edtd_curv_indc='Y' for specific PassId. 
If so only these rows will be shown, if not - rest of rows, according to condition `where (cnt>0 and edtd_curv_indc='Y') or cnt = 0`.
In answer I ignored columns using function `fget_log_curv_spec`, they are not important for this example.
I also changed old-style joins to ansi syntax.